# Can't bind to scope using vm. notation in controller/html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an update form using a route parameter to get the ID of the item I need. This is working as intended. Part of having the update form is to retrieve stored values and bind them to the form.

If I have my model set to something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Event_Desc" data-ng-model="eventdescription" required />
```

And my controller is set as follows (note, that is calling a REST service using ng-resource).

```
appItem.get({
        Id: $routeParams.Id
    }, function (result) {
        $scope.eventdescription = result.Title;
    });
```

It will properly set the field value to the value stored in the database on the form. However, if I attempt to use vm. notation as follows, it returns an error of "Unable to set property 'eventdescription' of undefined or null reference"

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Event_Desc" data-ng-model="vm.eventdescription" required />
```

Controller:

```
appItem.get({
        Id: $routeParams.Id
    }, function (result) {
        $scope.vm.eventdescription = result.Title;
    });
```

Why can't I set the $scope of vm.eventdescription?

Comment: Are you trying to use the "Controller As" syntax?

Comment: Yes I am. The controllers are tied to page level via the routing where the path, view, and controller are designated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to instantiate vm before use it like this

```
$scope.vm = {};

appItem.get({
        Id: $routeParams.Id
    }, function (result) {
        $scope.vm.eventdescription = result.Title;
    });
```

Comment: That did the trick. I had tried the var vm = this; but it did not work for me.

Comment: If you are using the Controller As syntax you shouldn't have to instantiate vm nor should you really be using $scope if you can avoid it.

Comment: Odd, as that is what I am using. Could it be different if I tied the controller to the page versus a surrounding div?

Comment: I thought you said you were setting it in the route? Can you edit your post to show where your are setting the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first initialize `vm` after you define your controller by doing

```
var vm = this;
```

And then set your value like

```
vm.eventdescription = result.Title;
```