# Can't bind function to scope using vm. notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

*Note: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814593/cant-bind-to-scope-using-vm-notation-in-controller-html), because I do instantiate vm. before using it.*

I'm injecting the controller into a directive. This is the controller basic setup:

```
function graphicDialogController($scope, $element) {
 $scope.data = {};
 var vm = this;
 vm.open = openDialog;
 vm.setType = setType;
 //this function is available via vm.
 function openDialog(data) {
        $scope.data = data.annotation;  
    }
 //but this isn't.
 function setType(graphic) {
        $scope.data.tag = graphic.tag;
        console.log($scope.data)
    }
```

However, if I bind `setType` directly to `$scope` like so

```
$scope.setType = function (graphic) {
        $scope.data.tag = graphic.tag;
        console.log($scope.data)
    }
```

all works fine.

Both functions are called on `ng-click`.

I would like to use vm. notation for consistency, so any pointer to what I'm missing would be appreciated.

This [simplified example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EgHFP5gGsXcHBqUG32rd?p=preview) actually works, but in my case the controller is injected in the directive and I'm not sure I can reproduce o it in a demo.

Comment: Could you share how you're trying to use it?

Comment: for the lazy techies out there, can you create a plunkr :-)

Comment: using $scope.*** and vm.*** simultaneously is strange idea

Comment: @PetrAveryanov agreed. I'm in the process of changing that.

Comment: @Thangadurai I've added a demo